# Estimate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I am concerned with the following sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}_{\displaystyle ~.}$$

It seems that sum must be computed by someone, but I do not know.

By the way, I can figure out a power series relevant to that sum. To be precise, set $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$ $(n\ge 1)$ and $T_0 = 0$, and thus $2^{-n}\cdot T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}$. One can use the standard way to determine the power series $$G(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} (2^{-n}T_n) ~ x^n=\sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}~ x^n = \frac{2}{2-x} \ln \frac{1}{1-x}~~~(0\le x <1).$$

However, it is not easy to evaluate the sum $T_n$ by means of the generating function $G(x)$.

Comment: take a look at the sum $\int_1^x(1+t+t^2+...t^{n-1})dt$

Comment: Mathematica sums this in terms of the Lerch transcendent. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function

Comment: According to Maple it is: $-i\pi -{2}^{n}{\itL erchPhi} \left( 2,1,n \right) +{\frac {{2}^{n}}{n}$  Without dollars: -i\pi -{2}^{n}{LerchPhi} \left( 2,1,n \right) +{\frac {{2}^{n}}{n}

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k/k = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k/n + \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k(1/k - 1/n)$ $\approx 2 \times 2^n/n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2^k \frac{n-k}{nk}$ etc. I'd say more but it's a pain to typeset comments.

Answer (score 1):

Set $f (x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i$, and let $g$ be an anti-derivative, so $g = \sum x^{i+1}/(i+1)$. Then evaluating the constant properly, your sum is just $g(2)$. Doesn't this yield a pretty good closed form? Or is it just a restatement of your original problem?

Comment: It looks to me like that is just a restatement. The denominator for $n=100$ is the least common multiple of the odd numbers up to $100$. What type of closed form do you have in mind which is compatible with that value? Normally, an expression with a summation from $0$ to $n$ is not considered a closed form.

Comment: Since $g(x)=\sum_{i\ge 0} x^{i+1}/(i+1)$ is divergent when $x\ge 1$, we cannot hold the desire in that way. But thanks for your attention.